# I cannot figure out why my Java code is erroring

Tags: java

My title was "Java program is giving cannot find symbol error" but it didn't let me put that.

I've seen similar questions to this asked, but I still cannot figure out what is wrong in my code. I have two separate classes, and I am getting the "cannot find symbol" error when the second class creates the object "HeartRates". Please help, code is pasted below.

First class:
https://pastebin.com/Lb4GqS4J

```
public class HeartRates {
// Set variables
public String firstName, lastName;
public int birthYear, age, maxHeartRate, minTargetHeartRate, maxTargetHeartRate;

public HeartRates(String firstName, String lastName, int birthYear) {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.birthYear = birthYear;
```

Second class:
https://pastebin.com/EyCax1Xq

```
    // Create object
    HeartRates person = new HeartRates(firstName, lastName, birthYear);
```

Comment: are those classes in the same package? are you using an IDE (IntelliJ/Eclipse/NetBeans)? what does the IDE suggest to fix that? do you import one class from the other?

Comment: How are you compiling your code? Please be specific (if you're using the command line, exactly what command are you using?)

Comment: check your classpath

Comment: your two pastebin links are the same

Comment: They're in the same project (but they're separate .java files), I am using Eclipse and it doesn't say what to do to fix it (like in the editor there's no red line or anything), what do you mean import one class from the other? And I am compiling it in Eclipse. And I fixed the pastebin links.

Answer (score 0):

Your second class actually isn't a class.  It's just an instance of your first class.  Add a main() to your code to see it run.  Also, when you create your instance of the class you need to give it actual variables.  You listed frstname, lastname and birthyear but neve define them.  Here's code that should help you out:

UPDATED INTO TWO CLASSES:

first class:

```
public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args){
       String firstname = "Bobby";
       String lastname  = "Jones";
       int birthyear    =  1953;

       HeartRates person = new HeartRates(firstname,lastname, birthyear);
       System.out.println(person.firstName); 
    }
}
```

second class:

```
public class HeartRates {
    // Set variables
    public String firstName, lastName;
    public int birthYear, age, maxHeartRate, minTargetHeartRate, maxTargetHeartRate;

    public HeartRates(String firstName, String lastName, int birthYear) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.birthYear = birthYear;
    }

    // Set firstName
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    // Get firstName
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    // Set lastName
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    // Get lastName
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    // Set birthYear
    public void setBirthYear(int birthYear) {
        this.birthYear = birthYear;
    }

    // Get birthYear
    public int getBirthYear() {
        return birthYear;
    }

    // Calculate age
    public int getAge() {
        return age = 2020- birthYear;
    }

    // Calculate maxHeartRate
    public int getMaxHeartRate() {
        return maxHeartRate = 2020 - age;
    }

    // Calculate minTargetHeartRate
    public int getMinTargetHeartRate() {
        return minTargetHeartRate = (int) (.5 * maxHeartRate);
    }

    // Calculate maxTargetHeartRate
    public int getMaxTargetHeartRate() {
        return maxTargetHeartRate = (int) (.85 * maxHeartRate);
    }
}
```

Comment: So I should add a main to the class that doesn't have one? This is for a programming assignment and it requires two separate java files. The pastebins show the full code for both files.

Comment: Java programs are traditionally invoked from the main method.  I only see one class one class on pastebin which I've copied.  What's the actual assignment?  If you need to use two classes what does each represent?

Comment: The two pastebin links are for the two files (when I originally posted the question they were the same link by mistake, but it's fixed now). And the assignment is for one class to have methods to set/get names, calculate target heart rate, max heart rate, and various things. With the other class (in a separate .java file) to ask for an input of name and birth year, then use the first class file to process and calculate all the stuff, then have the second class file print everything out. https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20200210000646AAZG9MQ may be a simpler way to put this if neede

Comment: That code is giving me the same error... Could it be something like my Eclipse is configured wrong?